# Does Java allow me to passively add data to outgoing network packets?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, middleware

I'd like to passively include additional data on outgoing packets and retrieve it from incoming packets.  Is there a way to do this in Java?  Basically I need a method for hooking into otherwise shimming my own sublayer in the network stack.

Comment: So you're saying is it possible to take a Java program that currently works with networking... and hijack its packets to modify their contents? Or is it possible to put a Java program in between a working server and working client, slurp in packets from it, modify them, and then send them back on their way?

Comment: Maybe implementing Your own Socket?

Comment: @glowcoder more like the former: I want to provide a mechanism for a program to use the networking capabilities of Java as if they're stock, but have a layer of information automatically added to outgoing packets and extracted from incoming packets.

Comment: @Rekin that's my best guess at a solution, but I'm throwing this out there to see if perhaps there's some better way to swing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to do it in C++ is libpcap or Winpcap libraries. Its Java wrapper has also been implemented, and can be [found here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t100034.html).

For packet injection issues, you may use [libnet](http://libnet.sourceforge.net/). Unfortunately, it does not have any java wrappers and you should write your own java wrapper by jni.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - pcap is a great way to capture packets and search for the data I'm adding.  That gets me half way there, but I'm still looking for a way to passively hook into and inject data in outgoing packets.

Comment: If you are going to hook into and inject data into packets, you can use Netfilter. Unfortunately, it is a kernel mode packet capturing and injection module, but lots of libraries provide user mode access to its features. I am not aware of any Java wrapper for it, but you may write your own wrapper for the needed services.

Comment: @Evan, "passively" inject data? How is that "passive"? ;-)

Comment: @hsalimi that Netfilter suggestion is top notch advice and probably will be the way to go long term.  Turn that into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mike - good point: passive is probably the wrong term here.  Instead what I'm looking for is to develop a package that allows someone to use it with an absolute minimum of effort.  They import the package, enable it, and it takes care of hooking into the network communications of the program using my package in such a way that it can pass and receive data relevant to it without the program importing my package having to do anything else special.  I called that "passive" thinking that would be the way to describe it from the viewpoint of the person using the package.